# Cakephp 2.2.4 does not save Auth User Info after using a alternative authenication

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to create an authentication for facebook users. Right now I check to see if a fb user id exist in my database, if it does then it authenicates, if not, then it data mines the users facebook info and creates a user and then authenicates. It works successfully, the problem is, if I use something like `$this->Auth->user('id');` the values return back null. I am curious on what I maybe doing wrong. below is my code

```
public function fb_authenticate($data) {
    $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'fbid', 'password' => 'fbpassword');
    $this->loadModel('User');
    $user_record = $this->User->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array('fbid' => $data['user_id'])
    ));
    if(empty($user_record)) {
        $fbu = $this->Facebook->getUserInfo($data['user_id']);
        $user_record = array(
            'User'=>array(
                'username'=>$fbu->username,
                'fbid'=>$data['user_id'],
                'oauth_token'=>$data['oauth_token'],
                'access_token'=>$data['access_token'],
                'firstname'=>$fbu->first_name,
                'lastname'=>$fbu->last_name,
                'fbpassword'=>$this->Auth->password($data['user_id']),
                'role'=>'user'
        ));     
        $this->User->create();
        $this->User->save($user_record,null);
    }
    if (!$this->Auth->login($user_record)) {
       $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
```

It authenicates and lets the user in, but it does not store the users info in the Auth component session. what could be the problem ??

if I debug `debug($this->Auth->user())` I can see the data but if I pull a field individually `debug($this->Auth->user('id'));` it returns `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$this->Auth->login($user_record)`

to `$this->Auth->login($user_record['User'])`.

Comment: that'll do it. had the same issue a few days ago

Comment: @numerical25 Btw in the case when you create a new user the user array you pass to login() doesn't have an `id` key, so fix that.